# Rendering items not showing up

Tags: react-native

im writing a todolist with reactnative using hooks , however when rendering todo items , its not showing up, any advice to fix this
thank you so much for your help!!!

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
    import { StyleSheet, FlatList, Text, View } from 'react-native';



    export default function App() {
      const [todos, setTodos] = useState([
        { text: 'budddy', key: '1' },
        { text: 'helloddd', key: '2' },
        { text: "hellddo", key: '3' }
      ])
      return (

        <View style={styles.container}   >

          <View style={styles.content}>
            <FlatList data={todos} renderItem={({ item }) => {

              <Text> {item.text}</Text>

            }} />

          </View>




        </View>
      );

    }

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        paddingTop: 30,
      },
      content: {
        padding: 40
      },

    })
```

Comment: You're missing `return`... `return <Text>{item.text}</Text>`

Answer (score 1):

Check the renderItem code you need to add return or use the implicit return of arrow function

```
 <FlatList data={todos} renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <Text> {item.text}</Text>

            )} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `extraData` property on your `FlatList` component.

As per documentation:

Bypassing `extraData={this.state}` to FlatList we make sure `FlatList` will `re-render` itself when the `state.selected` changes. Without setting this prop, `FlatList` would not know it needs to `re-render` any items because it is also a `PureComponent` and the prop comparison will not show any changes.

here is the example code (documentation)

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  TouchableOpacity,
  FlatList,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
} from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

const DATA = [
  {
    id: 'bd7acbea-c1b1-46c2-aed5-3ad53abb28ba',
    title: 'First Item',
  },
  {
    id: '3ac68afc-c605-48d3-a4f8-fbd91aa97f63',
    title: 'Second Item',
  },
  {
    id: '58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d72',
    title: 'Third Item',
  },
];

function Item({ id, title, selected, onSelect }) {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() => onSelect(id)}
      style={[
        styles.item,
        { backgroundColor: selected ? '#6e3b6e' : '#f9c2ff' },
      ]}
    >
      <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState(new Map());

  const onSelect = React.useCallback(
    id => {
      const newSelected = new Map(selected);
      newSelected.set(id, !selected.get(id));

      setSelected(newSelected);
    },
    [selected],
  );

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={DATA}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <Item
            id={item.id}
            title={item.title}
            selected={!!selected.get(item.id)}
            onSelect={onSelect}
          />
        )}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
        extraData={selected}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
  },
  item: {
    backgroundColor: '#f9c2ff',
    padding: 20,
    marginVertical: 8,
    marginHorizontal: 16,
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 32,
  },
});
```